# switch mod rewritten URL

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, 301-redirect

We are using a mod rewritten URL within our PHP site, this is the rewrite rule we are using:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^.]+)/([0-9]+)/([^.]+)/([0-9]+) categories.php?c_id=$2&filters=$3&_p=$4&area=category&areaname=$1
```

However, a user of a different system is switching to our setup and wants to 301 all their old pages to their new equivalents. So, for example, this URL:

```
http://domain.com/categories/clothing/5/1
```

becomes:

```
http://domain.com/category/clothing/5/0-0-0-0/1
```

Is it possible to do this in a single rewrite rule or rewrite match (or similar), my intial thought was something like this would work:

```
RewriteRule /categories/(.*)/(.*)/1 /category/$1/$2/0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0/1 [R=301,L]
```

Also tried this with RedirectMatch which also doesnt work:

```
RedirectMatch /categories/(.*)/(.*)/1 http://domain.com/category/$1/$2/0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0/1
```

it doesn't, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed myself with this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /categories/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) http://domain.com/category/$1/$2/0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0/$3
```